Woocommerce remove plugin filter and replace with my own
I'm trying to customize a plugin function for my needs, and have managed to get my altered version to show up as required.
Unfortunately I can't work out how to remove the original function, so now have two instances showing up.
Here's the original function from the plugin:
function aspwc_split_package_total_rows( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    if ( get_option( 'advanced_shipping_packages_display_separately', 'no' ) != 'yes' ) {
        return $total_rows;
    }

    /** @var WC_Order $order */
    $shipping_items    = $order->get_items( 'shipping' );
    $key_position      = array_search( 'shipping', array_keys( $total_rows ) );
    $new_shipping_rows = array();

    foreach ( $shipping_items as $item ) {
        $package_name = $item->get_meta( 'package_name' ) ?: str_replace( ':', '', __( 'Shipping:', 'woocommerce' ) );

        $new_shipping_rows[ 'shipping_' . $item->get_id() ] = array(
            'label' => $package_name . ':', // Package name
            'value' => '<strong>' . $item->get_name() . ':</strong> ' . aspwc_get_shipping_to_display( $item, $order, $tax_display ) . '<br/><small>' . $item->get_meta( 'Items' ) . '</small>',
        );
    }

    // Remove original shipping line - Only when new rows are set (which should only happen when package names are stored)
    if ( ! empty( $new_shipping_rows ) ) {
        unset( $total_rows['shipping'] );
    }

    // Add package line(s)
    array_splice( $total_rows, $key_position, 0, $new_shipping_rows ); // splice in at position 3

    return $total_rows;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'aspwc_split_package_total_rows', 10, 3 );

Which I'm trying to remove using:
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'aspwc_split_package_total_rows', 10, 3 );

And my custom function that is replacing it:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_split_package_total_rows', 10, 3 );

function custom_split_package_total_rows( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    if ( get_option( 'advanced_shipping_packages_display_separately', 'no' ) != 'yes' ) {
        return $total_rows;
    }

    /** @var WC_Order $order */
    $shipping_items    = $order->get_items( 'shipping' );
    $key_position      = array_search( 'shipping', array_keys( $total_rows ) );
    $new_shipping_rows = array();

    foreach ( $shipping_items as $item ) {
        $package_name = $item->get_meta( 'package_name' ) ?: str_replace( ':', '', __( 'Shipping:', 'woocommerce' ) );

        $new_shipping_rows[ 'shipping_' . $item->get_id() ] = array(
            'label' => $package_name . ':', // Package name
            'value' => aspwc_get_shipping_to_display( $item, $order, $tax_display ) . '<br/><strong>via ' . $item->get_name() . '</strong><br/><small>' . $item->get_meta( 'Items' ) . '</small>',
        );
    }

    // Remove original shipping line - Only when new rows are set (which should only happen when package names are stored)
    if ( ! empty( $new_shipping_rows ) ) {
        unset( $total_rows['shipping'] );
    }

    // Add package line(s)
    array_splice( $total_rows, $key_position, 0, $new_shipping_rows ); // splice in at position 3

    return $total_rows;
}

Everything works as it should, but I can't work out why remove_filter isn't doing anything.
Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!


remove_filter should have only three attributes. So, try the following remove_filter code
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'aspwc_split_package_total_rows', 10 );



If it still not working try it inside init or plugins_loaded hooks. Check the following code.


    function gs_plugins_loaded(){
        remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'aspwc_split_package_total_rows', 10 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_split_package_total_rows', 10, 3 );
    }
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'gs_plugins_loaded');



Hi GS_, thank you so much! Option 2 worked perfectly for me :)
